# Seeking counterexample or proof for equivalence of two separation properties

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Two points $x,y$ of a topological space are said to be *distinguishable* if at least one has a neighborhood not containing the other, and *separated* if each has a neighborhood not containing the other.

It is readily seen that in an $R_0$ space (one in which distinguishable points are separated), separated points have disjoint closures. I'm curious, however, if the $R_0$ condition is necessary for separated points to have disjoint closures. Does anyone know of an example of a non-$R_0$ space in which separated points have disjoint closures? Alternately, does anyone know of a proof that non-$R_0$ spaces will necessarily have separated points with non-disjoint closures?

**Edit**: coffeemath cleverly pointed out a trivial counterexample in the comments below. Does anyone know of a *non-trivial* counterexample? In particular, a space such that:

- there exist separated points in the space,
- there exist distinguishable, non-separated points in the space, and
- separated points in the space have disjoint closures.

Comment: The space with two points $a,b$ and open sets $\phi,\{a\},\{a,b\}$ is non-$R_0$. Since it actually has no separated points, one can say "separated points have disjoint closures" is vacuously true.

Comment: Ah! I skipped the two point space in my tests. (I must have subconsciously been looking for non-trivial counterexamples.) I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Do you also mean to stipulate that the non-$R_0$ space be such that any two points in it be distinguishable?

Comment: I don't require a $T_0$ space, no. On the other hand, I don't require a non-$T_0$ space, either. From a $T_0$ counterexample I can easily construct a non-$T_0$ counterexample, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=\{1,\dots,n\}$, and let let $X=\Bbb N$ with the topology generated by the base

$$\{\{0\}\}\cup\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\;.$$

Then all pairs of points are distinguishable: if $m<n$, then $m$ has an open nbhd not containing $n$. $0$ and $1$ are isolated points and hence separated. Finally, $\cl\{0\}=\{0\}$ and $\cl\{1\}=\Bbb Z^+$, so $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ have disjoint closures.

Comment: Very nice! Just what I needed (now that I've confirmed the details). Any insight into how you came up with it?

Comment: Perhaps it's something you encountered before? Just curious.

Comment: @Cameron: No, I've played very little with anything below $T_1$; I just saw something that would work.